# Fill zeros for missing values in range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to list a set of numbers within a range with their respective counts,
but include a zero where the value does not appear a table row.

For example,

```
create table score (
  n int
);
insert into score values (3);
insert into score values (1);
insert into score values (1);
insert into score values (5);
insert into score values (5);
insert into score values (5);
```

I can do

```
select n, count(n) from score
group by n order by n;
```

to give

```
 n | count
---+-------
 1 |     2
 3 |     1
 5 |     3
```

but instead I would like

```
 n | count
---+-------
 0 |     0
 1 |     2
 2 |     0
 3 |     1
 4 |     0
 5 |     3
```

I'm aware of `generate_series(0, max(n))`, but I'm not sure how to progress from here.

I could do this programatically at the application level, but for my own education
I'd like to learn how I can do this directly using a postgres query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a query like this that uses a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
  series, COUNT(score.n)
FROM
  generate_series(0, (SELECT max(n) FROM score)) series
  LEFT JOIN score
  ON series=score.n
GROUP BY
  series
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a51cb/1).